# Form to partially pay for Event Attendance

Tags: civievent, personal-campaign-pages, payment

I want to create a payment form to allow users to pay towards someone's event attendance.

Given a Contribution ID, how can I create a link to a page that will accept payments towards that Contribution?

Do I have to do this through Personal Campaign Pages, or is there a way without that overhead?

JohnFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a Payment to an existing Event Registration:

URL = /civicrm/payment?action=add&reset=1&component=event&id=88&cid=101

where cid = contact_id; and id=participant

[image]

There is a tiny button -> submit credit card payment -> but I don't think it's a public link (perhaps you can work the permissions)

[image]

Comment: And for anyone who may be interested in using this outside an event context, the URL is /civicrm/partialpayment?reset=1&id=29&cid=6&action=add&component=contribution&mode=live where ID is the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *Line Items*. Create a *Price Set* with the Attendee Name(s)/Contribution Id(s) that you would like to have available for people to help pay. Donors can enter the amount they want to give toward specific attendee(s). You will have to manually apply these contributions to the attendee's event fee. We do this for tuition here https://radiusinternational.org/paytuition/

The other way to do this is to use *Contribution Notes* via *Profiles*. Then the donor would just write in the name that they want to have the money applied to. The downside here is the limited placement of Profiles on the contribution page. Neither of the 2 placement options really puts the *Notes* anywhere logical in relation to giving form. The *Notes* are not next to the contribution label so then you have to add a description telling donors where to find the Notes further down the page.

Comment: interesting. would a variation to the second idea be to put a Contact Reference field in there rather than using Notes

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you are asking about having A pay for B's attendance, then yes PCP is the way to go. Will depend on just how many As and how many Bs you expect to be using the system

Comment: Hi Petednz, thanks for the response. 

Please can you tell me if: a) I should only maintain one contribution for the registration, and then just record payments against that (I take action when the amount is reached), or b) if I should create each contribution as a separate contribution?

Comment: Really can't comment meaningful. Not something I have ever needed to deal with. And not sure I quite understand your comment as not sure whether to be reading 'PCP' each time you use the word 'contribution' or not.

Comment: No, I meant contribution!